# javadoc of `java.time.DayOfWeek#minus(long)`

Tags: java, javadoc, java-time

The [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#minus(long)) writes:

> The calculation rolls around the start of the **year** from Monday to Sunday.

Why does it use "year"?

I also found in `plus()` it's

> The calculation rolls around the end of the **week** from Sunday to Monday.

And in `java.time.Month`, both `minus()` and `plus()` uses "year".

Comment: This looks like copy&paste error. You should file a bug report for that.

Comment: You can submit a bug here: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

Comment: Submitted a bug report on this, under review.

Answer (score 1):

This is reported in [JDK-8326158](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8326158) and confirmed to be a typo.
Now fixed in [JDK23 ea](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk23/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#minus(long))